# Mod_rewrite help for wordpress

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress site that has a very big database. There are many cases of typo errors in the title and slugs. I normally do a search and replace to correct the typos.

Can anyone help me in mod_rewrite rules to 301 redirect my old URL to the correct URL?

my site is using the following structure:

www.domain.com/shop/xxx-**blackk**-xx-xx
www.domain.com/shop/**blackk**-xx-xxx
www.domain.com/shop/xxx-xx-**blackk**

How do i redirect the old URL above (with typo) to the new URL (after corrected to **black**).

Your help is much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use a find-and-replace on the url?

`RewriteRule ^(.*)blackk(.*)$ $1black$2 [R=301]`

Comment: Yes I can find and replace on the URL. The purpose of this is to redirect the Search Engine visits (all the pages has been indexed).

Comment: I think that there's a misunderstanding. That rule should "find and replace", i.e. redirect the URL from the browser, could you use that?